# What does で do in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particles

I know what で is used for most cases, but I cannot seem to understand its use in this sentence would you please explain this sentence and the use of で

そのセリフは セコイで　ハナコ

Comment: Probably need more context. I think this で is the て-form for だ.

Comment: ^「せこい+だ」 (i-adjective + cupula だ) はないです・・

Comment: This usage of で is prevalent in Kansai dialects. It can be paraphrased as セコイよ in standard Japanese.

Answer (score 3):

Is this sentence uttered by a Kansai dialect speaker? I think the で is a sentence-ending particle (終助詞) in Kansai dialect. せこいで（i-adjective + で) means せこいぞ or せこいよ （i-adjective + ぞ/よ）in standard Japanese.

Examples of "i-adjectives+で":

> 「ずるいで」 ≈ 「するいぞ」
> 「ええで」 ≈ 「いいよ」

This で is used this way:

> あるで。（verb+で） ≈ あるよ。
> 帰ったで。 ≈ 帰ったよ。
> 知らんで。（negative+で）≈ 知らないよ。
> 持ってへんで。/ 持ってないで。 ≈ 持ってないよ。
> 日曜日やで。（noun+copulaや+で）≈ 日曜日だよ。
> きれいやで。（na-adjective+で）≈ きれいだよ。